# What is the source of the word "Rabbi"?

Tags: hebrew, words, rabbis

What is the source of the Hebrew word "Rabbi" - which is commonly applied to a Rav, Rosh Yeshiva, etc.?

Comment: What do you mean by "source"? Etymology? First use? Halachic source indicating it should be used?

Comment: @Community Is there a policy about changing the question almost 2 years after asking it and when there are already quality answers?

Comment: @DoubleAA Ask [Meta].

Comment: It has been asked here: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1229/759

Comment: Closed pending an [edit] clarifying what is meant by "source" here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rabbi is Roshei Teivos R'osh B'nei Y'isroel ([Taamei HaMinhagim Likutim #85](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&st=&pgnum=540&hilite=)).

Most likely the current English term derives from the original word Rabbi.

Comment: That is a reference to "רַבִּי" (which originally referred to one who has received real semicha) and not to the modern English term "Rabbi" which is used for any religious leader of Jews and not just for תלמידי חכמים.

Comment: @Yahu - So what?

Comment: @AdamMosheh, so it doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: I would say most likely the current English term derived independently from the post-facto Rashei Teivot.

Comment: The fact is there are no non Jewish Rabbis. Rabbi is a exclusive Jewish term.

Comment: Is your answer really "The word Rabbi derives from the word Rabbi"?

Comment: Yes it derives from the Hebrew word rabbi.

Comment: I don't know what games you're playing in the question, but I'm trying to say that the acronym developed after the existence of the Hebrew word. That's what post-facto means.

Comment: @msh210 Well it does now, now that the question has been --changed-- updated.

Comment: Based on all the comments I realized that my question was misunderstood. Due to that the question and my answer have been updated. DoubleAA you are correct that the acronym developed after the existence of the Hebrew word.

Comment: @GershonGold, if the acronym developed after the Hebrew word, how could it the acronym be the Hebrew word's source?

Answer (score 6):

In the Online Etymological Dictionary's [entry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rabbi&allowed_in_frame=0) on the corresponding English word, it says that the Hebrew word is Mishnaic Hebrew for "my master," combining "*Rav*" - meaning "master" or "great one" with the suffixx "*-i*" - meaning "my." "*Rav*," in turn, is associated with the Semitic root "R-B-B," which means "to be great or numerous."

(You can find much more on this root in the ["Resh" chapter (PDF)](http://www.hebrewetymology.com/chapters/resh.pdf) of the [Hebrew Etymology Project](http://www.hebrewetymology.com/).)

Answer (score 4):

Unkelus translates the word "Sar" ("officer") to mean "Rav" ("Rabbi"). Officer of God, I guess? (See [Bereshit 26:26](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/u/up0106.htm#719)).

[image: וַאֲבִימֶלֶךְ אָתָא לְוָתֵיהּ מִגְּרָר וְסִיעַת רַחְמוֹהִי וּפִיכֹל רַב חֵילֵיהּ׃‏]